# HTML and Wordpress link

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a problem with html links in `wordpress`.
For example if I want to add:

```
<a href="#div1">Dvi1</a>
```

and

```
<div id="div1">
text
</div>
```

If I click on `div1` I'm redirecting to homepage, not going to the `div1` location(`<div id="div">`). What could be the problem?

**PS:** If I use adblock it works, without it, it doesn't.

Comment: Can you show the final output of the `a` tag? I think wordpress might be imposing something on it. In Chrome, Right Click > Inspect Element on the `Dvi1` link.

Comment: `<a href="#div1">First Div</a>`

Comment: Maybe you can have some script that captures the click input on any anchor and processes it, because your anchor and element look right. Also for this to work you should have one and only one item with the anchors id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anchor tag to achieve your functionality...

Place `<a name="div1"></a>` as the first line in your DIV and then when you click on the link it should take you there without any issues.